# upgrading from diamondback to electric. problems with turtlebot?

Tags: turtlebot, ros-diamondback, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, is there any other option to upgrade than uninstalling one and installing the other?

If I'm working with the turtlebot and I have electric in the workstation and diamondback in the turtlebot laptop will it work?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11529/upgrading-from-diamondback-to-electric.-problems-with-turtlebot?/) by [apalomer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1165/apalomer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 318 on 2011-10-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both distributions can be installed together on any system.

However, only one at a time should be present in your `$ROS_ROOT` and `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variables.

You should not attempt to run nodes built against different distributions together, whether on separate machines or a single one.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-10-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2